# Browser extension: adding div to DOM so it is on top of everything (on top of elements being intended to be themselves on top of everything too)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, z-index

I am creating an extension for web browser.

It puts a div upon certain words on the HTML page, adding it to main body level.

I see that HTML and CSS can have zIndex settings so the extension has to take them into account because it wants its divs to be displayed on top of everything, even if the HTML wants some of its elements to be on top of everything.

Also parent elements are important because they can set the zIndex to child ones.

It is an extension so it has to be the "master" of the page and so it must have the last word on zIndex values.

How to achieve that?

Comment: @misorude You read the other question so I wonder how you ask this: divs are added to document not the elements, in fact, and they get hidden by zIndex settings as you pointed out in the comments to that question.

Comment: I mean they are appended to the body element.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options in this situation:

1. Use an obscene value for your z-index (bilion 9's should do it);
2. you should add the div to the body tag (so it is as up in the DOM as possible) and check the z-index of all it's siblings. After that add that z-index + 1 to your div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if the HTML page is designed with this trick itself and they set the zIndex to the number you suggested the trick is made in vain. And those numbers can be dangerous in javascript I think.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about option 2 - you can use a setinterval and run your z-index checking code a couple of times after DOM ready to make sure you are still have the top z-index.

Comment: It is not possible to be sure the HTML page designer hasn't used some special javascript constant like the maximum number or floating point numbers or even the Infinity, and different browser implementation would be taken into account. I think the numeric solution is not good.